# mod_rewrite multiple RewriteCond conflict

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a Problem with mod-rewrite.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent]  
    # For all files not found in the file system, reroute the request to the
    # "index.php" front controller, keeping the query string intact
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# IE Cache fix?
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A1
Header append Cache-Control must-revalidate
```

Redirecting doesn't work and no Styles or Images are showing.

If those three lines are comment out, it works:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But I need those to redirect any wrong entery to the root. How does this work together? Or why it doesen't work like this?

Comment: So what do the http servers log files say what the requets get written to, so that they fail?

Comment: I just added the part with:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent]

First I had just the rule with the redirecting rule missing files / direcories. That was also working fine. But those both RewriteRules together do not work for me.

Comment: You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `L` flag to your redirect. If you don't have one, the request will get flagged as a redirect and mod_rewrite will continue to run the rest of your rules. So this line needs an `L`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

If you have relative URL issues with your images or styles, try adding this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```